# api for retrieving object at a specific gps coordinate

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gps, openstreetmap

I have been reading the google maps api and the openstreetmap api, but i cannot find if they offer the following functionality:

I need to find out if at a specific gps coordinate there is a building or a street.

Do you know of any api offering this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder how you could missed that if you already did look at the documentation.

Of course OpenStreetMap can do this. There is the [main API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6) (which is primarily for editing and not for bulk querying!) where you can [retrieve all map data within a specified bounding box](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Retrieving_map_data_by_bounding_box%3a_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fmap).

Example:

> http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=13.76500,51.05600,13.76515,51.05615

This will return all objects between latitude *51.05600* and *51.05615* and longitude *13.76500* and *13.76515*. For how to interpret the returned XML file read [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) in the [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org).

In order to know if a specific object is a building, a street or something else you have to look at the [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). Buildings are usually tagged using the [building key](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3abuilding) and can either be a single [node, a way or (rarely) a relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements). Streets are usually *ways* and are tagged using the [highway key](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3ahighway).

Comment: i have seen that function, what i was missing is the key description.

Comment: I see. The API is just for accessing the data (actually, it is just one of many ways to access it) whereas the keys and their different values are completely independent from the API and created by regular OSM contributors.